# InternalResourceViewResolver cannot find page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have next project structure:

[image]

WebMvcConfiguration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.test.controller")
public class WebMvcConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver() {
        return new InternalResourceViewResolver("/WEB-INF/view/", ".html");
    }
}
```

WebAppInitializer class:

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webApplicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        webApplicationContext.scan("com.test.configuration");
        webApplicationContext.setServletContext(servletContext);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servletDispatcher =
            servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(webApplicationContext));
        servletDispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servletDispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

CustomRestController class:

```
@RestController
public class CustomRestController {
    @GetMapping(value = "/rest", produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    public String main() {
        return "main";
    }
}
```

CustomPageController class:

```
@Controller
public class CustomPageController {
    @GetMapping("/page")
    public String main() {
        return "main";
    }
}
```

Rest controller work as it should. But PageController fails with this Exception:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.noHandlerFound No mapping for GET /WEB-INF/view/main.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to enable DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer in WebMvcConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.test.controller")
public class WebMvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver() {
        return new InternalResourceViewResolver("/WEB-INF/view/", ".html");
    }
}
```